# Checking blank texbox but with integer and double variables

Tags: vb.net, integer, field

I´ve a problem to check texbox if it´s is blank. For example  it works for string:

```
 Dim endurance As String = endurancetxt.Text
    Dim gsout As String = gsoutxt.Text
    Dim gshome As String = gshometxt.Text
    Dim pnr As String

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(endurancetxt.Text.ToString()) Then
        MessageBox.Show("I need more info")
        Return
    ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(gsoutxt.Text.ToString()) Then
        MessageBox.Show("I need more info")
        Return
    ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(gshometxt.Text.ToString()) Then
        MessageBox.Show("I need more info")
    End If

    pnr = (endurance * gsout * gshome) / (gsout + gshome)
    pnrtxt.Text = CStr(CSng(pnr))
```

But the problem it´s mathematical calculations and I use string...

Are there anyway to use integer, double and single variables because if I use a integer variable for example it shows a exception message:

```
If endurancetxt.Text="" Then
MessageBox.Show("I need more info")
Return
```

Regards

Comment: Use `Integer.Parse()` to convert the text contents then compare.  There is of cource also `Integer.TryParse()`, `Double.Parse()` etc

Comment: Thanks Plutonix. I´m going to investigate how is the syntax.Many thanks